# How to resolve dependency injection for nuget packages

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0

I never published any nuget package before so have some questions in my mind. I have an application in .net core 2.2 in which I have a separate .net standard  library (Samples.Shared) that contains the interfaces that I want to publish as a nuget package because I need the same interfaces in 5 different solutions. Now the implementation of those interfaces is in a separate business layer i.e Samples.Services. In .net core I can resolve dependency in startup class like:

```
services.AddTransient<IRepository, Repository>();
```

But I will only expose the shared library that only contains interfaces so how will I resolve dependency of IRepository in other solution? The Samples.Service layer also contains some nuget packages that are injected in the service's constructor and reference to some ohter dll like Sample.Entites
Two of the solutions in which I need these interfaces are console applications and the other 3 are .net core applications.

Comment: Your implementation is either generic and applicable to multiple projects or specific to a particular application. If it's specific to a particular application, then the implementation should live within that application, and there's no issue. If it applies to multiple applications, then it, too, should be in a class library (maybe even the same class library) and each project that needs it will need to reference that library,

Comment: @ChrisPratt do you have a code sample?